# How would you suppress values below a threshold and replace with a string in Python

Tags: python, function, typeerror

I am trying to replace values below a limit (usually 10) in a dataframe and replace with a string. I was attempting this in a function in order to make it as reusable as possible.

This is what I currently have:

```
def limit(data, limit = 10):
    column = data.select_dtypes(include=['int64']).columns.tolist()
    rule = data[column] < limit
    data.loc[rule.any(axis = 1), cols] = 0
    column = data.columns.tolist()
    data[data[column] == 0] = f'Less than {limit} starts'
    return data

DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Australia', 'United Kingdom', 'USA', 'Japan'],
                          'Participants': [30,2,4,11],
                          'Passed': [20,15,2,7})

DataFrame = limit(DataFrame, limit = 10)
```

There are two issues with the above code:

1. I am looking for a table which only amends the values less than 10, however the above code amends all items in the same row, For example, in Japan, the participants (11) are also amended when they shouldn't be.
2. I keep getting an error message when I apply the f-string to label the empty cells with a label. The error message is:
   `TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value`

Any clues as to what might be causing these issues?

Comment: Thank you! That worked really well! I was wondering, if I wanted to go on and use that table to work out % or something, would it be an issue where there is a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def limit(data, threshold=10):
    cols = data.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns
    data[cols] = data[cols].mask(data[cols]<threshold, f"Less than {threshold} starts")
    return data

>>> limit(df, 10)
          Country         Participants               Passed
0       Australia                   30                   20
1  United Kingdom  Less than 10 starts                   15
2             USA  Less than 10 starts  Less than 10 starts
3           Japan                   11  Less than 10 starts
```